# Get the indices of the array after sorting in golang

Tags: sorting, go

I know we can use

```
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(example)))
```

to sort a array.

But how can I get the indices of the array?

e.g.

```
example := []int{1, 25, 3, 5, 4}
```

I want to get the output: 1, 3, 5, 4, 2

Comment: FYI, your `1, 3, 5, 4, 2`, should actually be `0, 2, 4, 3, 1`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make a wrapper for `sort.IntSlice` that remembers the indexes and swaps them when it swaps the values:

```
type Slice struct {
    sort.IntSlice
    idx []int
}

func (s Slice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.IntSlice.Swap(i, j)
    s.idx[i], s.idx[j] = s.idx[j], s.idx[i]
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/LnSLfe-fXk.

**EDIT:** As DaveC mentioned in the comments, you can actually wrap around `sort.Interface` to create a data structure for any sortable type:

```
type Slice struct {
    sort.Interface
    idx []int
}

func (s Slice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.Interface.Swap(i, j)
    s.idx[i], s.idx[j] = s.idx[j], s.idx[i]
}
```

Comment: Nice! You gotta love embedding!

Comment: @Ainar-G what if the data is [1.1 1.2] these float number. I changed IntSlice to Float64Slice, but it does not work

Comment: Or, if you don't know what type of `sort.Interface` you'll have something like: https://play.golang.org/p/lRuKrhGxYM to wrap any `sort.Interface` rather than `sort.IntSlice`. The only user visible difference is the convenience `New…` function that takes a variadic argument list.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good! But I needed a version of it that "didn't touch" my slice.

You can do it like this:

```
type sortable struct {
    nums, idxs []int
}

func (s sortable) Len() int           { return len(s.nums) }
func (s sortable) Less(i, j int) bool { return s.nums[i] < s.nums[j] }
func (s sortable) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.nums[i], s.nums[j] = s.nums[j], s.nums[i]
    s.idxs[i], s.idxs[j] = s.idxs[j], s.idxs[i]
}

func sortAndReturnIdxs(nums []int) []int {
    idxs := make([]int, len(nums))
    for i := range idxs {
        idxs[i] = i
    }

    sort.Sort(sortable{nums, idxs})

    return idxs
}
```

And then you can just call the function on your slice:

```
func main() {
    nums := []int{4, 1, 6}

    fmt.Println(sortAndReturnIdxs(nums)) // [1 0 2]
    fmt.Println(nums)                    // [1 4 6]
}
```

The function returns the indices, and sorts the array in place.

Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/7tli8tNeWNt

Answer (score 0):

You can also just get the indices and avoid mutating the slice in-place, see https://github.com/mkmik/argsort