# Golang: Find two number index where the sum of these two numbers equals to target number

Tags: performance, dictionary, go, slice

The problem is: find the index of two numbers that `nums[index1] + nums[index2] == target`. Here is my attempt in `golang` (index starts from 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var nums = []int{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 25182, 25184, 25186, 25188, 25190, 25192, 25194, 25196} // The number list is too long, I put the whole numbers in a gist: https://gist.github.com/nickleeh/8eedb39e008da8b47864
var target int = 16021

func twoSum(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    if len(nums) <= 1 {
        return 0, 0
    }
    hdict := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 1; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if val, ok := hdict[nums[i+1]]; ok {
            return val, i + 1
        } else {
            hdict[target-nums[i+1]] = i + 1
        }
    }
    return 0, 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(twoSum(nums, target))
}
```

The nums list is too long, I put it into a gist:
https://gist.github.com/nickleeh/8eedb39e008da8b47864

This code works fine, but I find the `return 0,0` part is ugly, and it runs ten times slower than the `Julia` translation. I would like to know is there any part that is written terrible and affect the performance?

**Edit:**
Julia's translation:

```
function two_sum(nums, target)
    if length(nums) <= 1
        return false
    end
    hdict = Dict()
    for i in 1:length(nums)
        if haskey(hdict, nums[i])
            return [hdict[nums[i]], i]
        else
            hdict[target - nums[i]] = i
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: is your list always sorted? If yes there there is much better algorithm without need to use a map. Also `i+1` and `i < len(nums)` doesn't look right. You will get out of bounds access.

Comment: Please show the Julia translation that you are comparing to.

Comment: Also how do you measure run time of both programs?

Comment: @kostya Thanks! No. the list is not sorted. I'll think again on the `i+1` part.

Comment: @CodingPickle Julia's translation added. (The nums is too long to paste here. I put it into the gist link.)

Comment: @kostya I measure the two programs in Windows PowerShell `Measure-Command { ./twoSum.exe }` command for golang; Julia's @time macro for julia run time. (I don't know how to build an `.exe` file for julia)

Comment: What commands do you measure? Both for go and julia? What times do you get?

Comment: @kostya Julia: `@time` `9ms`.  Go:  `Measure-command`: `90ms` .

Comment: I wonder if this is some Windows problem (do you have anti-virus?). I get about 7ms on my linux box. And benchmark function just for twoSums without executable overhead says it is 3.5 ms: http://play.golang.org/p/oTvNlEN6py

Comment: @kostya I agree with you, the computer I'm using now is slow, both hardware and system. But I'm surprised that the Julia running on the same platform/computer, is so fast. As you said, maybe the performance problem is caused by the windows executable overhead.

Comment: It is not fair to say that julia is faster in this case because you are benchmarking different things. The equivalent measurement in Go would look like: http://play.golang.org/p/NzUbkK-S9v

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion if no elements found adding up to `target`, best would be to return values which are invalid indices, e.g. `-1`. Although returning `0, 0` would be enough as a valid index pair can't be 2 equal indices, this is more convenient (because if you forget to check the return values and you attempt to use the invalid indices, you will immediately get a run-time panic, alerting you not to forget checking the validity of the return values). As so, in my solutions I will get rid of that `i + 1` shifts as it makes no sense.

Benchmarking of different solutions can be found at the end of the answer.

#### If sorting allowed:

If the slice is big and not changing, and you have to call this `twoSum()` function many times, the most efficient solution would be to sort the numbers simply using [`sort.Ints()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints) in advance:

```
sort.Ints(nums)
```

And then you don't have to build a map, you can use binary search implemented in [`sort.SearchInts()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts):

```
func twoSumSorted(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    for i, v := range nums {
        v2 := target - v
        if j := sort.SearchInts(nums, v2); v2 == nums[j] {
            return i, j
        }
    }
    return -1, -1
}
```

**Note:** Note that after sorting, the indices returned will be indices of values in the sorted slice. This may differ from indices in the original (unsorted) slice (which may or may not be a problem). If you do need indices from the original order (original, unsorted slice), you may store sorted and unsorted index mapping so you can get what the original index is. For details see this question:

[Get the indices of the array after sorting in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141202/get-the-indices-of-the-array-after-sorting-in-golang)

#### If sorting is not allowed:

Here is your solution getting rid of that `i + 1` shifts as it makes no sense. Slice and array indices are zero based in all languages. Also utilizing `for ... range`:

```
func twoSum(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    if len(nums) <= 1 {
        return -1, -1
    }
    m := make(map[int]int)
    for i, v := range nums {
        if j, ok := m[v]; ok {
            return j, i
        } 
        m[target-v] = i
    }
    return -1, -1
}
```

If the `nums` slice is big and the solution is not found fast (meaning the `i` index grows big) that means a lot of elements will be added to the map. Maps start with small capacity, and they are internally grown if additional space is required to host many elements (key-value pairs). An internal growing requires rehashing and rebuilding with the already added elements. This is "very" expensive.

It does not seem significant but it really is. Since you know the max elements that will end up in the map (worst case is `len(nums)`), you can create a map with a big-enough capacity to hold all elements for the worst case. The gain will be that no internal growing and rehashing will be required. You can provide the initial capacity as the second argument to `make()` when creating the `map`. This speeds up `twoSum2()` big time if `nums` is big:

```
func twoSum2(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    if len(nums) <= 1 {
        return -1, -1
    }
    m := make(map[int]int, len(nums))
    for i, v := range nums {
        if j, ok := m[v]; ok {
            return j, i
        }
        m[target-v] = i
    }
    return -1, -1
}
```

#### Benchmarking

Here's a little benchmarking code to test execution speed of the 3 solutions with the input `nums` and `target` you provided. Note that in order to test `twoSumSorted()`, you first have to sort the `nums` slice.

Save this into a file named `xx_test.go` and run it with `go test -bench .`:

```
package main

import (
    "sort"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkTwoSum(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        twoSum(nums, target)
    }
}

func BenchmarkTwoSum2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        twoSum2(nums, target)
    }
}

func BenchmarkTwoSumSorted(b *testing.B) {
    sort.Ints(nums)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        twoSumSorted(nums, target)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkTwoSum-4              1000       1405542 ns/op
BenchmarkTwoSum2-4             2000        722661 ns/op
BenchmarkTwoSumSorted-4    10000000           133 ns/op
```

As you can see, making a map with big enough capacity speeds up: it runs **twice** as fast.

And as mentioned, if `nums` can be sorted in advance, that is **~10,000** times faster!

Comment: @EmilVikström The functions return **indices**. `-1` is a valid integer but it is an invalid **index**.

Comment: Wow, impressive answer! ;) I suspect using `2 * len(nums)` as initial map capacity might make TwoSum2 slightly faster.

Comment: @kostya Nope, tested it and it made it worse (was 20% slower compared to using `len(nums)` initial capacity).

Comment: @icza, thanks for checking. This just confirms that reasoning about performance is very hard ;)

Comment: @kostya Not necessarily. `len(nums)` will avoid rehashing. But using bigger initial capacity will result in more memory usage, and it might be harder to maintain (bigger areas to allocate, might be harder to find sufficient contiguous space). The gain that you would observe with bigger capacity is not experienced as the map is not "fully" populated even with `len(nums)` (only in worst case).

Comment: @icza, yes, I've just realized that len(nums) could be enough to avoid rehashing, depending on the input.

Answer (score 1):

If `nums` is always sorted, you can do a binary search to see if the complement to whichever number you're on is also in the slice.

```
func binary(haystack []int, needle, startsAt int) int {
    pivot := len(haystack) / 2
    switch {
    case haystack[pivot] == needle:
        return pivot + startsAt
    case len(haystack) <= 1:
        return -1
    case needle > haystack[pivot]:
        return binary(haystack[pivot+1:], needle, startsAt+pivot+1)
    case needle < haystack[pivot]:
        return binary(haystack[:pivot], needle, startsAt)
    }
    return -1 // code can never fall off here, but the compiler complains
              // if you don't have any returns out of conditionals.
}

func twoSum(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    for i, num := range nums {
        adjusted := target - num
        if j := binary(nums, adjusted, 0); j != -1 {
            return i, j
        }
    }
    return 0, 0
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/BW9R4vL6bB)</kbd>

Or you can use `sort.SearchInts` which implements binary searching.

```
func twoSum(nums []int, target int) (int, int) {
    for i, num := range nums {
        adjusted := target - num
        if j := sort.SearchInts(nums, adjusted); nums[j] == adjusted {
            // sort.SearchInts returns the index where the searched number
            // would be if it was there. If it's not, then nums[j] != adjusted.
            return i, j
        }
    }
    return 0, 0
}
```